# Hibernate criteria: how to order by two columns and get the earliest changed value of them?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a database entity (hospital) with modifiedDate(datetime) and createdDate(datetime) columns and my requirement is whichever value is the earliest it should top the fetch list. Below is the piece of code I tried:

```
Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria(Hospital.class);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("createdDate"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("modifiedDate"));

List<Hospital> hospitals = criteria.list();
```

**EDIT**:
For example, I have 3 hospitals which i have created today,yesterday and day before yesterday now when I fetch the list it should give me hospitals ordered by createdDate in this order :

1. H today
2. H yesterday
3. H day-before-yesterday

Now when I modified ->(H yesterday) and fetch the list again the order should be :

1. H yesterday (modified today)
2. H today
3. H day before yesterday

Hope this clears out the doubts , if not i will try to frame it again.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, please see my edited question.

Comment: That's not what I understood. From what you added in your question, just ordering on `modifiedDate` DESC first then `createdDate` DESC should work. i.e. switch your two `criteria.addOrder(...)` statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i think i had failed to explain you, say for example after modification of H yesterday (modified today) hospital , if i create a hospital (H now ) then it should be the top most hospital and second should be the (H yesterday). That is why I mentioned in my question 'Earliest one from them'...

Comment: When creating an object, do you assign value of `createdDate` to `modifiedDate` ? If so, my previous comment is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Order.asc in this case. If you will use Order.desc you will have situation when the newest one (biggest values) would be on Top.

Comment: yes, my requirement is showing the earliest created/modified hospital to be the top most record, hence i am using desc.

Comment: I would use just one criteria. After creation I would place the same date to createdDate and modifiedDate, and then use only modifiedDate.